# error: no matching function for call to 'Processus<std::vector<double> >::minmax(const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&) const'|

Tags: c++

I have a problem, I have my class and my minmax function coded as below

```
template<typename T>
class Processus {
public:
    typedef pair<double, T> state;
    typedef vector<state> result_type;

    Processus(int n = 0) : v(n+1)
    {
        Schedule w(n);
        auto i_w = w.begin();
        for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it, ++i_w) it->first = *i_w;
    };
    Processus(const Schedule& w) : v(w.size()) {
        auto i_w = w.begin();
        for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it, ++i_w) it->first = *i_w;
    }
    ~Processus() {};
    virtual result_type operator()() = 0;

    auto begin() const { return v.begin(); };
    auto end() const { return v.end(); };

    pair<T, T> minmax() const;

protected:
    vector<state> v;
};
    
pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> minmax(const vector<double>& v1, const vector<double> v2){
    pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> cur(v1, v2);
    auto i_min = cur.first.begin(), i_max = cur.second.begin();
    for (auto it = v1.begin(), it2 = v2.begin(); it != v1.end(); ++it, ++it2, ++i_min, ++i_max) {
        *i_min = ::min(*it, *it2);
        *i_max = ::max(*it, *it2);
    }
    return cur;
}


template<>
inline pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> Processus<vector<double>>::minmax() const {
    pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> cur(begin()->second, begin()->second);
    for (auto it = begin()+1; it != end(); ++it) {
        cur.first = minmax(it->second,cur.first).first;
        cur.second = it->second.minmax(cur.second).second;
    };
    return cur;
};
```

However, I get the error :

> error: no matching function for call to 'Processus<std::vector<double> > >::minmax(const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&) const'

Which correspond to this line:

```
cur.first = minmax(it->second,cur.first).first;
```

Comment: this code is hard to read, you really should introduce some `typedef` or `using` statements to clean it up

Comment: please dont panic when someone tells you to change the code. You now put the aliases there, but they are only defined in the scope of the class. When you modify the code make sure it still produces the same error

Comment: now `T` is not declared...

Comment: @Elezan To avoid mistakes like this, you might like to run your code through one of the many online compilers that exist to check it for errors.  Personally, I like [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of `Processus::minmax()`, your intent is to call your standalone 2-parameter `minmax()` function.  However, from the error message, it is clear that the compiler is trying to call `Processus::minmax()` recursively instead, which does not work since `Processus::minmax()` does not take in any parameters.

To call the standalone function of the same name, prefix the call with the `::` scope operator:

```cpp
cur.first = ::minmax(it->second,cur.first).first;
```

Otherwise, rename the standalone function to something more unique.

Comment: Should that not be `std::minmax`?

Comment: @Paul No, it should not. Read the code more carefully, it is defining its own `minmax()` function above the definition of the `Processus::minmax()` method. The code is not trying to use [`std::minmax()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax), which is a completely different function